# How many bytes does this take to store in memory (assembly)

Tags: assembly

Hi i'm trying to understand how many bytes will be needed to store these numbers in memmory.

```
delta dw 0,1,2,3,00FFH,0AAAAh
```

and

```
message db "Hello", 0dh, 0ah, "carcar", '$'
```

Will each character take 1byte ? 
Thanks!

Comment: `dw` is `data word`, 2B.  Every element in the list takes 2B, obviously.  Downvoting for a trivial RTFM question.

Comment: You *do* know what `dw` means?

Comment: I'm just starting to learn assembly. Someone told me that, one character is one byte , and somewhere else, i saw that dw has 2bytes, so there was information conflict...

Comment: then db will be 1byte, correct ?

Comment: `nasm -f bin -o data.bin data.asm && dir data.bin` Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The first (using `dw`) will reserve 12 bytes.  The second will reserve 14.  The total is 26 bytes.  Here's why:

You correctly identify `DW` as "Define *Word*" which, as you were told, reserves two bytes.  Since you define six numbers and 2*6=12, twelve bytes total are allocated.

You also correctly identify `DB` as "Define *Byte*" which, unsurprisingly, allocates a single byte.  On top of this, in *this case*, characters are one byte in length.  Since the string that you define has 14 characters (including the trailing "$"), this reserves 14 bytes.

Comment: On close inspection, you're off by 1. There are **14** bytes in `message db "Hello", 0dh, 0ah, "carcar", '$'`

Comment: Miscounted.  Corrected.

Comment: Ah, missed that one.